# Any way to increase font size in Moon reader when reading pdf?

Tags: pdf, fonts

The font size when reading pdf in MoonReader is really small. Is there any way to increase it?

Comment: No. You can't change anything in a pdf, that's why I don't call them real "ebooks". You can't change the font, font size, have it rewrap to different device screen widths, etc. You can zoom in, then you have to scroll back and forth in the PDF, which is a pet peeve of mine for PDFs and poorly designed websites. It can also be very difficult or cost-prohibitive to extract data from some PDFs. Good for protecting IP, bad for sharing data.

Answer (score 2):

No - pdf's are statically sized documents.  One of the benefits of different formats such as EPUB and amazon's MOBI files are that they are reflowable and built with html and css. This is what allows you to adjust font size in *relation* to the container.   The text then *reflows* throughout the container at the new font level.

However, you can zoom on pdf's and as long as the document isn't one big image the fonts should stay highly readable.